# Simple Javascript output list to HTML question

Tags: javascript, html

My apologies for any confusion, and I forgot to mention that this is a React app, and the React folks frown upon the use of doc.getElement().innerHTML, so at minimum the app needs to be minimally compliant.

Here is my code, stubbed out - not to hide anything, but just for brevity:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table} from 'reactstrap';

function DrawTicket() {
    //ticket generator code
}

function LottoSimulator() {
    //declare vars
    //ticket tally buckets
    //loop over number of tickets "bought", compare against "winning" ticket
     ...code
    //build out the list of tickets for display: HERE IS MY PAIN POINT, I'M COMING OUT OF MY LOOP WITH EACH GROUP OF 6 NUMBERS AND I TRIED APPENDING A BREAK TAG, UNICODE, ESCAPED CHARS, AND EVERYTHING GETS PRINTED TO SCREEN INSTEAD OF GETTING RENDERED
        ticketList.push(yourTicket);
        ticketList.push(‘<br />');

        let ticketDisplay = {ticketList};
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Table responsive>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th className="text-center" colSpan="2">
                        <h5>Winning Numbers: {winningTicket.replace(/,/g, ', ')}</h5>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{zeroCount}</td>
                    <td className="text-left">of your tickets didn't match any numbers</td>
                </tr>    
                ...
                <tr>
                    <td>{sixCount}</td>
                    <td className="text-left"> of your tickets matched all winning numbers</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
           </Table>
Your tickets:<br />
        {
            <p><pre>{ticketList}</pre></p> //HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO OUTPUT THE LIST OF TICKETS
        }
        </div>
    )
}

export default LottoSimulator
```

I'm actually generating the "tickets" above the output of HTML (jsx) and I'm able to generate, for example 3 tickets, that get output to screen like this:

8,10,25,36,38,39 br 16,19,21,26,27,38 br 20,22,24,28,39,47 br (i had to remove the tag characters because stackoverflow is rendering correctly, unlike in my browser)

But the problem is the break tag is not being rendered as HTML, it's actually printing to the screen. Again sorry for the confusion, and in fact I have tried a lot of different things to solve, just can't seem to get that string formatted correctly to display each ticket on it's own line

Comment: If you push a bunch of HTML strings to an array, you have to do `container.innerHTML = elementsArray.join("");` when you're done. Please add an input and output example to your question.

Comment: FYI: this question got closed as "too broad", which is a subtle nudge that you should do way more research first (it's the only close reason that fits "read the docs")

Comment: i did read the docs guys, tried a whole bunch of different things before I posted, I can repost differently with all of the things i tried...

Comment: Please create a proper [mre] that shows what you've tried and how it fails.

Comment: Live example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yj0hwp18/

Comment: my apologies for any confusion, and I forgot to mention that this is a React app, and the React folks frown on the use of doc.getElement().innerHTML.
Here is my code, stubbed out - not to hide anything, but just for brevity:

Comment: Yeah, that little tidbit could've been mentioned from the start... ignoring that you have a "Word quote" `‘` in your code which causes a syntax error, you need `ticketList.push(<br />);` And just for reference, you could've simply used elements that get displayed in a column anyway, like `<li>`s or `<div>`s.

Comment: Forgot the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-blackwell-41zsz

Comment: Chris thank you your solution ( codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-blackwell-41zsz) worked; I know I tried just adding just the br tag (like you have it in your solution ```ticketList.push(<br />);``` ) but given the various permutations that I tried I somehow missed the simple solution. Trying to mark you answer as the solution, thanks again Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris thank you your solution ( codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-blackwell-41zsz) worked; I know I tried just adding just the br tag before I even posted here (like you have it in your solution ticketList.push(
); ) but given the various permutations that I tried I somehow missed the simple solution. Thanks again – Gossamer Winchell 
Credit to Chris G (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var listOfNums = [];
for (var ixef = 0; ixef < 5; ixef++) {
  listOfNums.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
}
var listOfNumsAsStr = listOfNums.join(',') + "</ br>";
document.getElementById('ticketList').innerHTML = listOfNumsAsStr;
```

```html
<div id="ticketList"></div>
```